# image are not shown properly in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html

![enter image description here][1]hy there i create a uploading information form.....
my html code is...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add New Templete</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php include 'side.php'; ?>
    <div class="main">
    <h2>Add New Templete</h2>
    <form action="add.php"method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table border="1px solid">
        <tr>
        <td>Templete Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="temp_name"></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Templete Category</td><td><input type="text" name="category"></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Templete Image</td><td><input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="102400" type="hidden"><input type="file" name="image"></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Templete Discription</td><td><input type="text" name="decp"></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Templete Quantity</td><td><input type="text" name="qty"></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Templete Price</td><td><input type="text" name="price"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        <td>    
        <input type="submit" value="ADD">
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the php code for inserting it into database...

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$name=$_POST['temp_name'];
$cat=$_POST['category'];
$image=$_FILES['image'];
$desc=$_POST['decp'];
$qty=$_POST['qty'];
$price=$_POST['price'];
$qry="INSERT INTO templetes(templete_name,category,image,description,quantity,price)VALUES('$name','$cat','$image','$desc','$qty','$price')";
$res=mysql_query($qry,$con);
if($res)
{

    header('location:product.php');
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

now i want to access it and show all the information in a manner, my show.php code is....

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM templetes");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$content = $row['image'];

header('Content-type: image/jpg');
     echo $content;


?>
```

but no data is accessed, my show.php code will not work, even it will not show image which i store in data base and also my image in database has not the correct size, mean the orignal size of image is 40.3kb and when it is saved in database the it,s size is just 5kb why?

> How to resize the image while saving it into mysql, like in yahoo
>   profile or g+ we select an image for our profile and it will fit in a
>   specified frame.

Comment: what is your table structure (e.g. output of `show create table templetes;`)?

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$name=$_POST['temp_name'];
$cat=$_POST['category'];
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])); //<== modification
$desc=$_POST['decp'];
$qty=$_POST['qty'];
$price=$_POST['price'];
$qry="INSERT INTO templetes(templete_name,category,image,description,quantity,price)VALUES('$name','$cat','$image','$desc','$qty','$price')";
$res=mysql_query($qry,$con);

mysql_close($con); // move this here, I think header() function prevents code placed after it to be interpreted.

if($res)
{

    header('location:product.php');
}

?>
```

use this to resize image : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.imagecopyresized.php

Comment: can you add the above code in my code, i can,t clearly understand your code,,,

Comment: your answer is nice the image is stored but data will not accessed? can you take a look at my show.php code

Comment: add `stripslashes()` when echoing `$content` : `echo stripslashes($content);`